# site/link for word count of quran?

Tags: quran, software, uloom-al-quran

Assalaam o alikum. 
Please guide me any link/website where i may post my any query word and in return i  get answer about how many times that particular word or sentence appears in quran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A concordance of Quran can be found at several places, [corpus.quran.com](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp) being one example.

Comment: not much user friendly

Comment: please guide any other link

Comment: I tried to search word rehman but i couldn't due to lack of user freindly page at that link

Comment: @engr maybe you should be more precise in your inquiry. The qur'an is in Arabic language so for this language the search works perfectly. If you use a transliteration than certainly you may have issues. You should better use English synonyms. IMO this is not an issue of the site not being user-friendly, but of wrong user expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Another site that allows you to search the transliterations is https://info.qurangateway.org. You have to register, but it seems even better than the islamicity link since it searches the transliteration (or English) rather than phonetically. You get more exact matches and it highlights the word in the transliteration and Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for result like

```
https://www.islamicity.org/ps/
```

so i got it and It answered my query(for search when we want to search through roman arabic script)